# Stack doesn't seem to apply package revision

Tags: haskell, package, haskell-stack

I had the following (excerpt of) `stack.yaml`:

```yaml
extra-deps:
  - bytestring-0.10.12.0
```

Then I wanted to install `cassava`, which I did by adding:

```yaml
extra-deps:
  - bytestring-0.10.12.0
  - cassava-0.5.2.0
```

But then I had this error on `stack build`:

```
In the dependencies for cassava-0.5.2.0:
    bytestring-0.10.12.0 from stack configuration does not match >=0.9.2 && <0.10.4  (latest matching version is 0.10.2.0)
needed due to my-project-0.1.0.0 -> cassava-0.5.2.0
```

To which I discovered that there's a revision (all of them from rev2 onwards) that deals with this explicit problem, by bumping the dependency on ByteString to `<0.12`.

Therefore `stack.yaml` now looks like this:

```yaml
extra-deps:
  - bytestring-0.10.12.0
  - cassava-0.5.2.0@rev:4
```

But nothing changes on `stack build`, I still got the same error. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can use `allow-newer: true`, but that's a bit sad. In any case I think you should report this as a bug on the `stack` issue tracker.